# Getting a random variable blur in my css

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, blur

I want the result of the math function into my css file, that the kind of blur is variable. But it doesn't work and I don't know how, because there are no errors. The variable number is between 1 and 5.

This is the Javascript code I'm using:

```
var minNumber = 1;
var maxNumber = 5;
var result;

var randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);

function randomNumberFromRange(min, max) {
    result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    return;
}


document.getElementById("test").style.filter = blur(result + "px");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set that style as a string:**

```
document.getElementById("test").style.filter = "blur(" + result + "px)";
```

```js
var minNumber = 1;
var maxNumber = 5;
var result;

var randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);

function randomNumberFromRange(min, max) {
  result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

document.getElementById("test").style.filter = "blur(" + result + "px)";
```

```css
#test {
  position: absolute left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 9999;
  opacity: .9;
}

#test2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
<div id="test2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your console. You should have an error saying `blur` is undefined.

`blur` is not a function defined in JS, but rather a CSS filter function, and as such should be set as a string in your case.

For example:

```
document.getElementById("test").style.filter = 'blur('+result+'px)';
```

If ES6 is possible in your case, you can also use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and plug the value as an embedded expression:

```
document.getElementById("test").style.filter = `blur(${result}px)`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass blur as a text value to the CSS filter property:

```js
var minNumber = 1;
var maxNumber = 5;
var result;

var randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);

function randomNumberFromRange(min, max) {
    result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    return;
}

console.log('random value for blur: ', result);
document.getElementById("test").style.filter = 'blur('+ result +'px)';
```

```html
<p id="test">test</p>
```